# How to retrieve existing model data and display on a custom odoo website module page

Tags: python, odoo-8, openerp-8

Am trying to retrieve project data from model project.project and display on a customized website module in odoo 8.

Am stuck on retrieving data via controller. See code below.

models.py

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

#Just inherit default odoo project.project fields

class project_category(models.Model):

_name='project.project'

_inherit='project.project'
```

controllers.py

```
class Website(http.Controller):
@http.route('/index',auth='public',website=True)
def list(self,**kw):
projects = http.request.env['project.project']
print "Test is below "
print projects # this prints project.project() which i think its an empty array. My goal is to retrieve projects and render them on

# template layout
return http.request.render('website.layout',
{'projects':projects.search([])
})
```

Any suggestions most welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue. I realized the array is empty because i was printing before calling search() method which performs read operation.

You can only print projects after calling projects.search([])

**Updated Controllers.py**

```
class Website(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/index',auth='public',website=True)
    def list(self,**kw):
        Projects = http.request.env['project.project']
        print "Test is below "
        arr = Projects.search([])
        print arr
        return http.request.render('website.layout',
               {'projects':Projects.search([])
     })
```

Result is:

project.project(21, 18, 20, 19, 22)

I then render this :

**templates.xml**

```
<t t-foreach="projects" t-as="project">
  <strong><t t-esc="project.name" /></strong>
  <b><t t-esc="project.description" /></b>
 </t>
```

Though Odoo renders this, am now getting a new error

QWebException: foreach enumerator 'projects' is not defined while rendering template 'website.layout'

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
from openerp.addons.web import http
from openerp.http import request


class WebsiteDemo(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/portal', type='http', auth='user', website=True)# Auth is for logged in users
    def display_project_data(self):
        cr, context, pool = request.cr, request.context, request.registry

        pro = pool.get('project.project')
        pro_ids = pro.search(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [], context=context)
        pro_data = pro.browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, hr_employee_ids, context=context)

        values = {
                  'projects' : pro_data
                  }

        return request.website.render("website.project", values)

     })
```